# Remove certain characters from file name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have four files in a directory let's say as following

```
Test_File_20170101_20170112_1.txt
Test_File_20170101_20170112_2.txt
Test_File_20170101_20170112_3.txt
Test_File_20170101_20170112_4.txt
```

and I want to merge them in order and want the final file as

```
Test_File_20170101_20170112.txt
```

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Look in the answer section for my comment as it is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ls *_[1-9].txt \
    | sed 's/_[1-9]\.txt//' \
    | sort -u \
    | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "cat {}_*.txt > {}.txt"
```

Explaining each step:

- `ls *_[1-9].txt`: list all files ending with `_1.txt`, `_2.txt` etc
- `sed 's/_[1-9]\.txt//'`: remove the extension and number suffix
- `sort -u`: unique file names (e.g. `Test_File_20170101_20170112`)
- `xargs ...`: for each file name, catenate each numbered file into a new file

You *could* extend this to a larger sequence, e.g. `_10.txt` etc, but you would need to be aware that the order would not be correct, as it would be in alphabetical order at the expansion of the final `*`, e.g. `_1`, `_10`, `_2`... Here are some approaches for this: [cat files in specific order based on number in filename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385357/cat-files-in-specific-order-based-on-number-in-filename)

Comment: Are you sure you've copied correctly? A single-line version would be: `ls *_[1-9].txt | sed 's/_[1-9]\.txt//' | sort -u | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "cat {}_*.txt > {}.txt"`

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake in copy paste. Works perfectly fine. Thanks

Comment: I'm scratching my head, wondering why `cat Test_File_20170101_20170112_?.txt
 > Test_File_20170101_20170112.txt` wouldn't solve this very specific problem. I guess since it's a poorly asked question, we have to make our own assumptions of the problem's realm.

Comment: The file name suggests that this is not a one-off problem, and the file name changes each day. A deleted answer posted earlier confirms that the file names are dynamic.

Comment: @cmbuckley : Your solution would not work, if there are no files matching the input pattern. Also, consider using `echo` instead of `ls` an `cp` instead of `cat`.

Comment: @user1934428 - I want the same thing if it matches then only move else do not move or rename. I posted the whole code in the answer and it is working.

Comment: @user1934428 of course it would not work if there are no files that match - what would you expect to happen in that scenario? I also have no idea why either of your suggestions would help — it needs to list files, and concatenate multiple files into a single file, so that sounds like a job for `ls` and `cat`.

Comment: @cmbuckley : If there are no files matching, I would expect either a graceful error message (something like "no file available"), or that the command acts as a no-op. Which behaviour is desired, is of course something only the OP can decide.

Comment: @cmbuckley : My proposal refered to use `echo` to generate a list of file names, instead of `ls`. I wanted to avoid using ls to generate a list of file names, but on second thought, I agree with you, that `echo` isn't a good idea either. Maybe it would be better to use a `for ... in ...` loop. This would also make the use of `sed` unnecessary, because the extension can easily be stripped using shell language only.

Answer (score 0):

I complete the following. Your doubt is fine but I was stuck at 1 point where @cmbuckley helped and my code is working as I expected. Thanks for your concerns and help. You can still correct my code if anything is not right but it is working fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

PDIR=$1
FDIR=$2

# Change the current working directory
cd "$PDIR" || exit;

# Count number of files present in the current working directory
c=$(ls -p | grep -v / | wc -l)

# Count number of iteration it needed for Loop
n=$(expr "$c" / 4)

# Move the first 4 sorted files.
# 1.Header File 2.Column Name File 3.Detail records file 4.Trailer record file
i=1
while [ "$i" -le "$n" ];
# Move first 4 files from source folder to processing folder
do mv `ls -p | grep -v / | head -4` "$PDIR"merge/;
# Change directory to processing
cd "$PDIR"merge/ || exit;
# Look for files ending with "_[1-9], sort and then merge them to one file and remove numeric from output file
ls *_[1-9].txt | sort -u | sed 's/_[1-9]\.txt//' | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c "cat {}_*.txt > {}.txt";
# Remove processed files
rm -f *_[1-9].txt;
# Move output file to Target directory
mv *.txt "$FDIR";
cd "$PDIR" || exit;
i=$(($i + 1));
done
```

Comment: You don't need to spawn a subprocess just for calculating `n`. You can do it with `((n=c/4))`, and the loop increment can be done with `((i++))`. BTW, the loop won't be executed, if the number of files inside the working directory is 1 or 2 or 3, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thank you @cmbuckley for the useful tip. As someone mentioned above, can I make sure that the first 4 files what I am picking are from the same group. For eg. following files got generated
<pre>
TEST_TYPE_A_1.txt
TEST_TYPE_A_2.txt
TEST_TYPE_A_3.txt
TEST_TYPE_B_1.txt
TEST_TYPE_B_2.txt
TEST_TYPE_B_3.txt
TEST_TYPE_B_4.txt
</pre>
It did not generate the 4th file in first group so it will move first 4 file and which will mess the data. What should I do to put a check in there so if any file is missing process break ?